# as3 What's the difference in declaring a variable?

Tags: actionscript-3

Sometimes you declare a variable this way. Does it change the way the game works in anyway? I saw some people do it different ways of these two.

```
var number:Number = new Number();
```

Sometimes like this

```
var number:Number;

number = new Number();
```

Comment: they are exactly the same.  One just has the convenience of being all on one line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a difference in your example, though if I end up reusing a variable many times (such as in a loop), then I'll do the second method to avoid redefining a variable over and over.

Example:

```
var someCalculatedIndex:int;
for(var counter:int = 0; counter < 1000; counter++){
    someCalculatedIndex = counter * counter;
}
```

as opposed to

```
for(var counter:int = 0; counter < 1000; counter++){
    var someCalculatedIndex:int = counter * counter;
}
```